# Angularjs $http.get call gives error on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie to angularjs and on the first example I try out for $http.get I get 
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module getHubViewer due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'getHubViewer' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

When I comment the get call, everything works just fine. Could anyone please help.

url: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ww4S2GgVXYGauwdbINJS?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="getHubViewer">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("getHubViewer", []);
  var MainController = function($scope, $http) {
    //var promise = $http.get('https:\\api.github.com\users\robconery');
    $scope.message = "Hello, Angular";
  };
  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http",MainController]);
}());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the backslashes to a slash:

`var promise = $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/robconery');`

It says "Unknown symbol" before the error you wrote. Search for those errors, they're less conspicuous than the long angular error messages, and they're usually what's causing the issue.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFBmbv6nBX3Hna0C36NM?p=preview)

Comment: I would say that the backslash needs to be forward slash... otherwise its a pretty strange URL :).

Answer (score 1):

use `/` instead of `\`
in url patern you shoud be use `/`

> var promise = $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/robconery');

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong "slashes". URLs consist of simple slashes "/" instead of the backslahes you are using.

Use https://api.github.com/users/robconery instead of https:\api.github.com\users\robconery

The error speaks for itself: "Illegal character". The backslash is reserved for escaping certain special characters.